# Python script to send mail with attachment getting Assertion Error

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, email

I am trying to send mail using python script. I tried without attachment it is working.

Now i tried with attachment i am getting assertion error.

Below is the code:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders
import os
import time
import random
msg_from = "xyz@abc.com"
to =  "xyz@abc.com"
text = "test-Hello"
subject = "Test"
f = "output1.pdf"

def generate_message_id(msg_from):
    domain = msg_from.split("@")[1]
    r = "%s.%s" % (time.time(), random.randint(0, 100))
    mid = "<%s@%s>" % (r, domain)
    return mid

def send_mail(msg_from, to, subject, text,
    files=[],server="10.10.10.10", debug=False):
    assert type(to)==list
    assert type(files)==list

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = msg_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    text = text.encode("utf-8")
    text = MIMEText(text, 'plain', "utf-8")
    msg.attach(text)

    msg.add_header('Message-ID', generate_message_id(msg_from))

    for file in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'
                        for file in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'
                       % os.path.basename(file))
        msg.attach(part)

    if not debug:
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
        smtp.sendmail(msg_from, to, msg.as_string())
        smtp.close()

    return msg
send_mail(msg_from, to, subject, text,files=[],server="10.10.10.10", debug=False)
```

Error i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testmail1.py", line 53, in <module>
   send_mail(msg_from, to, subject, text,files=[],server="10.10.10.10", debug=False)
File "testmail1.py", line 24, in send_mail
   assert type(to)==list
AssertionError
```

I am using from linux os and using python 2.7

Please help me to fix

Comment: Well `to` is a string and not a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `to` field should be a list, because you could theoretically send your email to multiple persons. So I'd suggest:

```
to =  ["xyz@abc.com"]
```

The `send_mail` method checks first if your `to` field is a list, that's why you're getting the error.

Also check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail)